# Get Custom Properties jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the value of custom proprieties using Jquery. i've an array of text input.
I write this code:

```
<div id="informazioniAggiuntive">
 <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){ ?>
  <div >
<input type=text placeholder="CAP.." id='<?php echo "cap".$i."[]"; ?>'   maxlength=3 size=3 />
<input type=text placeholder="Prov.." id='<?php echo "prov".$i."[]"; ?>' maxlength=2 size=2 />
<input type=text placeholder="Località.." id='<?php echo "loc".$i."[]"; ?>' class='loc' data-ind='<?php echo $i; ?>' />
  </div>
 <?}?>
</div>
```

and the JQuery code.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.loc').on('keypress',function (e) {
        //Here to get Value
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see the "loc" class as the "data-" tag.
Best Regards!

Comment: What's wrong with `attr()`?

Comment: when i write my code i write this line: var data = this.data('ind') and not var data = $(this).data('ind')... i mistake the '$' object

Comment: I see - read this: http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using data()

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.loc').on('keypress',function (e) {
        var data = $(this).data('ind')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to read the value of `data-*`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.loc').on('keypress',function (e) {
        //Here to get Value
        var ind = $(this).data('ind');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loc').on('keypress',function (e) {
         $(this).data('ind'); // to read data-ind attribute value
    });
});
```